# Encoding issue when reading file in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization, utf

I have a file containing

```
    foo = "Gro\xdfbritannien"
```

I'm using the following, but it always displays the original text with the \x

```
    import codecs
    f = codecs.open('myfile', 'r', 'utf8')
    for line in f:
      print line
      print line.encode('utf-8')
      print line.decode('utf-8')
```

I can't see how to display the proper encoded text, as when I'm doing

```
    >>> print u'Gro\xdfbritannien'
    Großbritannien
```

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: If your file literally has a quoted string with a backslash and an `x` in it, you'll need to parse the string literal with something like `decode('string-escape')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your file contains the line

```
foo = "Gro\xdfbritannien"
```

it contains an actual backslash character, followed by `x` , `d` and `f`. So if that line is read into a Python string, it is read as

```
'foo = "Gro\\xdfbritannien"'
```

(and since those are all ASCII characters, it doesn't matter if you open it with the `utf-8` codec or not).

So you need to decode it first using the  `string_escape` codec:

```
>>> foo.decode("string_escape")
'Gro\xdfbritannien'
```

and *then*  decode it to the correct Unicode object

```
>>> _.decode("latin1")
u'Gro\xdfbritannien'
```

which you can then print

```
>>> print _
Großbritannien
```

Comment: Thanks - works perfectly with print line.decode("string_escape").decode("latin1")

Answer (score -1):

There is no business of codec.
You should do like this 'foo = "Gro\xdfbritannien"'

```
>>> print u'Gro\\xdfbritannien'
Gro\xdfbritannien
```